# Bootstrap modal on a separated file doesn't close

Tags: php, html, css, bootstrap-4

I'm using **modal** from **bootstrap**. The modal opens but it doesn't close either with the cross or close button.

This is what I have on my **index.php** file:

```
<div id="editar" class="modal fade" role="dialog" tabindex="-1" aria-hidden="true">
</div>
```

And this is the modal which is in a separated **.php** file:

```
<div class="modal-dialog modal-lg">
        <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-header">
                <h4 class="modal-title">Editar Accion</h4>
                <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" id="cerrar">
                    <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
                </button>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-body">
                <input type="hidden" name="editar" value="<?php echo $id; ?>">
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label for="item_name">Accion:</label>
                    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="accion" value="<?php echo $accion; ?>">

                </div>
            </div>
        <div class="modal-footer">
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary mb-3" name="update" id="btn-editar"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-edit"></span> Editar</button>
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary mb-3" data-dismiss="modal"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-remove-circle"></span> Cancelar</button>
            </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

I have to keep them in two files.

Comment: Hi, a couple of questions. (1) Does it work properly when they're in the same file? (2) Are you sure you're including the modal with either **include** or **require** exactly inside the first modal div. (3) The modal is opening fine but not closing? Could you include the bit that's calling the modal.

Comment: Yes i have another modal in the same file and it works, but this one in especefically i have to keep it in 2 files php. The modal opens but doesn't close and the "cancel" button neither does it work, next I have another button that is to save the edition and it works perfectly

Comment: I have a question, what is the include or requiere for the modal?

Comment: I tried your code adding a button to call the modal and putting the modal in a separated php file and it works, so it's not an issue with the code you posted here. By **include** or **require** I mean how are you adding the modal into the index.php since you said you have it in two separated files? you'd have to do something like `include "editar_modal.php"` inside the `<div id="editar"></div>`. I think it's better if you post the whole code (both files) so I can try it myself and see where it's failing.

Comment: It is very difficult to refer the second page's modal to the first. It is better you call both the methods in one page and on the button click show a modal pop up.

Answer (score 0):

If you noticed my comment, I have told you its headache to use two different pages. Also it is not recommended way.

I have created a button for you and on the button click the modal shows up with cancel button that goes away when you click it. It is the way exactly you wanted afterwards.

```html
<html>
<head>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.7/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>

<div class="container">
  
  
  <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal">
    Click Me
  </button>

  
  <div class="modal fade" id="myModal">
    <div class="modal-dialog">
      <div class="modal-content">
      
        <!-- Modal Header -->
        <div class="modal-header">
          <h4 class="modal-title">Editar Accion</h4>
          <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
        </div>
        
        <!-- Modal body -->
        <div class="modal-body">
          <input type="hidden" name="editar" value="<?php echo $id; ?>">
          <div class="form-group">
                    <label for="item_name">Accion:</label>
                    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="accion" value="<?php echo $accion; ?>">
              
                </div>
        </div>
        
        <!-- Modal footer -->
        <div class="modal-footer">
             <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary mb-3" name="update" id="btn-editar"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-edit"></span> Editar</button>
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary mb-3" data-dismiss="modal"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-remove-circle"></span> Cancelar</button>
        </div>
        
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

I think it is better to make use of `JQuery` so that you can have more control over what happens (e.g: clear fields, etc) on the modal on close.

```
$(document).on('click','#button_id',function(e){
   e.preventDefault();
   //you can clear fields first if you need to
   $('#accion').val('');
   $('#modal_id').hide(); //close modal
});
```

Please remember to include the file into the `index.php`. Keeping modal in separate file will help you reuse the same somewhere in your code, that is if you keep your modal code dynamic enough.